# Unable to POST File from MVC Controller to Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I need to be able to `POST` a file from my `MVC` app to a separate Web API controller.

I am able to hit the API controller fine and upload a file via postman. When I try to hit the API controller from the `MVC` app I get no response from the API.

If I set a breakpoint on the API controller it will not get hit when I try calling it from the `MVC` app.

Here is my code from the `MVC` app:

```
public async Task UploadFiles(string filePath, HttpFileCollectionBase files)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
        string fileName = $"{filePath}/{file.FileName}";

        HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(filePath);
        HttpContent fileContent = new StreamContent(file.InputStream);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            formData.Add(stringContent, "filePath");
            formData.Add(fileContent, "fileContent");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("MY_API_URL/UploadFile", formData);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the web API code (this code works when I `POST` a file via postman, but will not be hit when called from the `MVC` app):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadFile")]
public async Task UploadFile()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new Exception(); //TODO: throw proper exception here
    }

    var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

    foreach (var stream in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
    {
        var fileStream = await stream.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        BlobStorageUtils.UploadFile("Test/test.png", fileStream);
    }
}
```

So the issue must be somewhere on my `MVC` app side, but I'm not exactly sure what it is.

Comment: not sure off the top of my head but you should be able to run a tool like fiddler (similar to postman if youre not familiar with it. you can issue requests to services but it also tracks all other network requests on your machine) and look at the request that is captured from the one that works and the one that doesn't. find the difference and you're golden. if no breakpoint is hit at all, my first guess would be that the route you're calling in the mvc app is incorrect

Comment: I'll see if I can use fiddlr to check out the request being sent out. The route is not incorrect because it's identical to the route I'm using in Postman, and that works just fine.

Comment: Perhaps it is blocked because the mvc runs on a different domain, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/cors).